# Get Metrics path throws connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port, prometheus

I use Grafana and Prometheus. Both are installed on the same server and I don't use docker.

Recently I've imported the Node-Exporter dashboard, and modified the `prometheus.yml` file like this:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "node"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

But the node job can't get up. It is down:

[image]

Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Are you running [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) on the host and binding it to port 9100? The error suggests that you're not. You should be able to browse|curl `http://localhost:9100/metrics` on the host.

Answer (score 0):

I have configuration:
prometheus in docker, node_exporter setup locally.
from docker localhost is localhost inside container.
I change

- targets: ['localhost:9100']
  to
- targets: ['172.17.0.1:9100']
  success. It`s for linux. check address by  'ip -4 addr show docker0'

Answer (score 0):

This DID work:

```bash
curl 172.17.0.1:9100/metrics
```

while this DID NOT work:

```bash
curl http://localhost:9100/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9100 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```